# trouble in newsfeed using ajax, it shows everything like a loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm actually working on a social media website using php and mysql,i have trouble in the creation of newsfeed using ajax,when i created the infinite scrolling newsfeed,everything works fine but the news feed never ends(i have only 12 posts in tabe) it shows everything repeatedly like a loop.

index_page.php

```
    <div class="post_area"></div>
    <img id="loading" src="assets/images/icons/loading.gif">

</div>

<script>

    var userloggedin = '<?php echo $userloggedin; ?>';

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#loading').show();

        //original ajax request for loading first posts
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=1&userloggedin=" + userloggedin,
            cache:false,

            success: function(data){
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.post_area').html(data);
            }
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var height = $('.post_area').height(); //div containing posts
            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
            var page = $('.post_area').find('.nextPage').val();
            var noMorePosts = $('.post_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();

            if((document.body.scrollHeight = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false'){
                $('#loading').show();

            var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                                    url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: "page=1&userloggedin=" + userloggedin,
                                    cache:false,

                                    success: function(response){
                                        $('.post_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //removes current .nextpage
                                        $('.post_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //removes current .noMorePosts

                                        $('#loading').hide();
                                        $('.post_area').append(response);
                                    }
                                });
                }//end of if

                return false;

        });// end of $(window).scroll(function());
    });

</script>
```

post.php(class)

```
        public function loadPostsFriends($data, $limit){

        $page = $data['page'];
        $userloggedin = $this->user_obj->getUsername();

        if($page == 1)
            $start = 0;
        else
            $start = ($page - 1 ) * $limit;


        $str=""; //string to return
        $data_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "select * from posts where deleted ='no' order by id desc");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($data_query) > 0){

                $num_iterations = 0; // number of items checked (not necessarily posted)
                $count = 1;

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data_query))

                {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $body = $row['body'];
                        $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                        $date_time = $row['date_added'];

                        //prepare user_to string so it can be included even if not posted to a specific user
                        if($row['user_to'] = "none"){
                            $user_to = "";
                        }
                        else{
                            $user_to_obj = new User($con, $row['user_to']);
                            $user_to_name =$user_to_obj->getFirstAndLastName();
                            $user_to = "<a href='" . $row['user_to'] . "'>" .$user_to_name . "</a>";
                        }

                        // check if a user who posted has their account closed
                        $added_by_obj = new User($this->con, $added_by);
                        if($added_by_obj->isClosed()){
                            continue;
                        }

                        if($num_iterations++ < $start)
                            continue;



                        //once 10 posts is loaded, break
                        if($count > $limit){
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            $count++;
                        }

                        $user_details_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "select first_name, last_name, profile_pic from users where username='$added_by'");
                        $user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
                        $first_name = $user_row['first_name'];
                        $last_name = $user_row['last_name'];
                        $profile_pic = $user_row['profile_pic'];



                        //Time Frame
                        $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $start_date = new DateTime($date_time); //time of post
                        $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //current time
                        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //difference between dates

                        if($interval->y >= 1)
                            {
                                    if($interval == 1)
                                        $time_message = $interval->y . " year ago"; //1 year ago
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; // more than 1 year ago
                            }

                        else if($interval->m >= 1)
                            {
                                    if($interval->d == 0)
                                        $days = " ago";
                                    else if($interval->d == 1)
                                        $days = $interval->d  . " day ago";
                                    else
                                        $days = $interval->d  . " days ago";
                                    if($interval->m == 1)
                                        $time_message = $interval->m  . " month" . $days;
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->m  . " months" . $days;
                            }


                        else if($interval->d >= 1)
                            {

                                    if($interval->d == 1)
                                        $time_message = "Yesterday";
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->d . " days ago";

                            }

                        else if($interval->h >= 1)
                            {

                                    if($interval->h == 1)
                                        $time_message = $interval->h . " hour ago";
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->h . " hours ago";

                            }

                        else if($interval->i >= 1)
                            {

                                    if($interval->i == 1)
                                        $time_message = $interval->i . " minute ago";
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->i . " minutes ago";

                            }

                        else
                            {
                                    if($interval->s < 30)
                                        $time_message = "Just now";
                                    else
                                        $time_message = $interval->s . " seconds ago";
                            }

                        $str .= "<div class='status_post'>

                                      <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                                          <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                                      </div>

                                      <div class='posted_by' style='color: #ACACAC;'>
                                          <a href='$added_by' id='user_names_in_post'> $first_name $last_name </a> $user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                                      </div>

                                      <div id='post_body'>
                                           $body
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                  <hr>";

                } // end of while

            if($count > $limit){
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPage' value='" . ($page + 1) . "'>
                        <input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='false'>";
            }
            else{
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='true'><p style='text-align: center;'> No more posts to show! </p>";

            }

          }// end of if

        echo $str;

    }//end of loadPostsFriends
```

ajax_load.php

```
    <?php 

include ("../../config/config.php");
include ("../classes/user.php");
include ("../classes/post.php");

$limit = 10; //numbr of posts to be loaded in one call;

$posts = new Post($con, $_REQUEST['userloggedin']);
$posts->loadPostsFriends($_REQUEST, $limit);

?>
```